PJSUA2 auto-declining recieved calls
I'm unable to receive calls on my PJSUA2 python script. I've simplified my script as much as possible to replicate the issue below. This simplified script is largely sourced from the PJSUA2 docs helloworld example and the receive calls doc. Whenever I run it and call the number for the associated device, the call fails immediately with a 603 Decline.
import pjsua2 as pj
import time


class MyAccount(pj.Account):
    def onRegState(self, prm):
        print("***OnRegState: " + prm.reason)

    def onIncomingCall(self, iprm):
        call = MyCall(self, iprm.callId)
        prm = pj.CallOpParam()
        prm.statusCode = 200
        call.answer(prm)


class MyCall(pj.Call):
    def __init__(self, account, call_id):
        pj.Call.__init__(self, account, call_id)


def pjsua2_test():
    # Create and initialize the library
    ep_cfg = pj.EpConfig()
    ep = pj.Endpoint()
    ep.libCreate()
    ep.libInit(ep_cfg)
    ep.audDevManager().setNullDev()

    # Create SIP transport. Error handling sample is shown
    sipTpConfig = pj.TransportConfig()
    sipTpConfig.port = 5060
    ep.transportCreate(pj.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, sipTpConfig)

    # Start the library
    ep.libStart()

    # Account configuration
    acfg = pj.AccountConfig()
    acfg.idUri = "sip:test@sip.pjsip.org";
    acfg.regConfig.registrarUri = "sip:sip.pjsip.org";
    cred = pj.AuthCredInfo("digest", "*", "test", 0, "pwtest");
    acfg.sipConfig.authCreds.append( cred );
    acfg.sipConfig.authCreds.append(cred)

    # Create the account
    acc = MyAccount()
    acc.create(acfg)

    return ep, acc  # Return the endpoint to keep it alive


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ep, acc = pjsua2_test()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Exiting...")
    finally:
        ep.libDestroy()

I've read previous similar questions and they all seem to center around GC, audio card issues or NAT issues. As you can see, I'm persisting my pjsua objects, so I don't believe it's GC. I'm using setNullDev(), so I don't believe it's audio card issues. And I've installed this into Vultr where they have directly attached IPv4 ips so that I can be assured its not NAT. However, I'm still unable to receive a call.
In case it's of interest, I deployed onto Vultr with their Ubuntu 22.04 image and the following script:
apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libasound2-dev wget python3 python3-dev automake autoconf libtool libpcre2-dev bison && apt install -y python3-setuptools && cd /usr/src && wget https://github.com/swig/swig/archive/refs/tags/v4.2.1.tar.gz && tar -xvf v4.2.1.tar.gz && cd swig-4.2.1 && ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install && cd /usr/src && wget https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/archive/refs/tags/2.14.1.tar.gz && tar -xvf 2.14.1.tar.gz && cd pjproject* && ./configure CFLAGS="-fPIC" && make dep && make && make install && cd /usr/src/pjproject*/pjsip-apps/src/swig/python && make && make install && python3 setup.py install

I'd greatly appreciate any help you all might be able to offer, thank you in advance!

Did you find out what was happening here? I stumbled upon the same issue, and if I raise an exception at the end of the onIncomingCall callback, call is accepted, otherwise pjsip auto-responds with 603. Could not yet figure out why and could find no documentation related to this.

Without looking at the logs, It will be difficult to give you a definitive answer, however, I think you need to have a full implementation of the call callbacks especially the ones which are used to setup media this one should be in the onCallMediaState()
            r = self.getMedia(mi.index)
            self.am = pj.AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(r)
            pj_ep = pj.Endpoint.instance()
            aud_dev_mgr = pj_ep.audDevManager()
            playback_dev_media = aud_dev_mgr.getPlaybackDevMedia()
            capture_dev_media = aud_dev_mgr.getCaptureDevMedia()
            self.am.startTransmit(playback_dev_media)
            capture_dev_media.startTransmit(self.am)

If you had provided the logs I would have been easy to pinpoint the source of the Call decline message. regards,
